# Is there a way to use weld and cdi-unit with java 11 openj9

Tags: java, jboss, weld, cdi-unit

I am using weld and cdi-unit with java 11-openj9 in a project, when I run my unit test, configured with @runWith(Cdirunner.class) I get this error "ClassNotFoundException: org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner"

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jglue.cdi-unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-unit</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is it happening only during test? No errors being shown in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, actually It is a batch, and when i lanch my Integration test it work but it not working only in test, I am using intellij 19.3 and here the satcktrace
`java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner not present
 at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46) at
com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
 at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused`

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner`

Answer (score 0):

Please use a newer version of cdi-unit, for example, 4.1.1.

There were changes implemented to support Java 9 and beyond.
See [Support for Java 9 and later](http://cdi-unit.github.io/cdi-unit/#support-for-java-9-and-later) for the reference.